# error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, compiler-errors

When I'm trying to build my VC++ code using 2010 I'm getting the error message

`> C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1.`

Please tell how to overcome this?

Comment: There are a significant number of results from a Google Search for `error MSB6006: “cmd.exe” exited with code 1` -- Can you share the results of your research?

Comment: Fix your pre/post build event script.

Comment: Getting an `error MSB6006: "LC.exe" exited with code -1`, I solved this by simply deleting the _content_ of the **licenses.licx** file.

Comment: I got this problem while running cmake. Reading through the cmake log file, I found a weird path clash with a irrelevant software.  I uninstalled the unrelated software, cmake succeeded.

Answer (score 13):

Navigate from `Error List Tab` to the Visual Studios `Output` folder by one of the following:

- Select tab `Output` in standard VS view at the bottom
- Click in Menubar `View > Output` or `Ctrl+Alt+O`

where `Show output from <build>` should be selected.

You can find out more by analyzing the output logs.

---

In my case it was an error in the Cmake step, see below. It could be in any build step, as described in the other answers.

```
> -- Build Type is debug 
> CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
>     A logical block opening on the line
>     <path_to_file:line_number>    
>     is not closed.
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem today, while I was upgrading some VC6 project to VC2012.

In my case, it was because some of the operation in Custom Built Steps failed.
In project properties, go to Custom Build Step, you can see there maybe some something in command line edit box. Open a windows prompt and paste the command to it. Run, check if there is something wrong and fix it.

If there is no command line in the project property Custom Built Step, maybe you should check properties of every single file of the project.

If the command line has some macro, replace it with an actual value.

Or you can echo the command in VS output window:

- `cd %(somedir)%`
- `echo %(somedir)%`

You won't miss it this way.

Comment: hi, I am facing the same problem and no customer build step command found? what you mean by check your properties of every single file of the project?

Answer (score 5):

`error MSB6006: "cmd.exe"` exited with code `-Solved`

I also face this problem . In my case it is due to `output exe` already running .I solved my problem simply close the application instance before building.

Comment: I have one instance of VS with my main project open, and a second one with a DLL plugin project. I had forgotten I had the main program running because it had hit an exception and it was no longer in the taskbar. I kept getting a similar error every time I tried to compile the DLL. Finally I found this question/answer. Saved me from having to ask on SO. OP needs to accept this answer.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this. double click this error leads to  behavior.

1. open .vcxproj file of your project
2. search for  tag
3. check carefully what's going inside this tag, the path is right? difference between debug and release, and fix it
4. clean and rebuild

for my case. a miss match of debug and release mod kills my afternoon.

```
          <Command Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">copy ..\vc2005\%(Filename)%(Extension) ..\..\cvd\
</Command>
      <Command Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">copy ..\vc2005\%(Filename)%(Extension) ..\..\cvd\
</Command>
      <Outputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">..\..\cvd\%(Filename)%(Extension);%(Outputs)</Outputs>
      <Outputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">..\..\cvd\%(Filename)%(Extension);%(Outputs)</Outputs>
      <Command Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">copy ..\vc2005\%(Filename)%(Extension) ..\..\cvd\
</Command>
      <Command Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">copy %(Filename)%(Extension) ..\..\cvd\
</Command>
      <Outputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'">..\..\cvd\%(Filename)%(Extension);%(Outputs)</Outputs>
      <Outputs Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">..\..\cvd\%(Filename)%(Extension);%(Outputs)</Outputs>
    </CustomBuild>
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually Just delete the build ( clean it ) , then restart the compiler , build it again problem solved .

Answer (score 2):

I also faced similar issue.

My source path had one directory with 'space' (D:/source 2012). I resolved this by removing the space (D:/source2012).

Comment: where was this path used?

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of future readers. My problem was that I was specifying an incompatible openssl library to build my program through CMAKE. Projects were generated but build started failing with this error without any other useful information or error. Verbose cmake/compilation logs didn't help either.

**My take away lesson is that cross check the incompatibilities in case your program has dependencies on the any other third party library.**

Answer (score 1):

Simple and better solution : 
%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe MyProject.sln
I make a bat file like this
**%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe D:\GESTION-SOMECOPA\GestionCommercial\GestionCommercial.sln
pause**

Then I can see all errors and correct them. Because when you change the folder name (without spaces as seen above) you will have another problems. Visual Studio 2015 works fine after this.

Comment: could you explain this in a little more detail, i am stuck with the same error.

Answer (score 1):

When working with a version control system where all files are read only until checked out (like Perforce), the problem may be that you accidentally submitted into this version control system one of the VS files (like filters, for example) and the file thus cannot be overridden during build.

Just go to your working directory and check that none of VS solution related files and none of temporary created files (like all moc_ and ui_ prefixed files in QT, for example) is read only.

Answer (score 1):

I was in a similar situation to the one described by "irsis".

I configured the project through CMAKE, and in CmakeList, I linked the OpenCV library to the project. However, when I updated the OpenCV version for another project, the path was changed and error occurred.

Check path of all related library.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be, that you deleted a file from your Project by just removing it in your file system, instead of removing it within your project.