# Strange internal compiler error in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio

In one of my classes `foo`, I insert values into some static member array, `static unsigned int index[9][9][9][9]`, with the following

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < 9; k++) {
        for (int l = 0; l < 9; l++) {
          if (index[i][j][k][l] != 100) {
            setIndex(i, j, k, l, &index[j][i][k][l]);
            setIndex(i, j, k, l, &index[i][j][l][k]);
            setIndex(i, j, k, l, &index[j][i][l][k]);
            setIndex(i, j, k, l, &index[k][l][i][j]);
            setIndex(i, j, k, l, &index[k][l][j][i]);
            setIndex(i, j, k, l, &index[l][k][i][j]);
            setIndex(i, j, k, l, &index[l][k][j][i]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The function `setIndex` is the following:

```
void foo::setIndex(int i, int j, int k, int l, unsigned int *p) {
  *p = getIndex(i,j,k,l);
}
```

and it needs

```
unsigned int foo::getIndex(int i, int j, int k, int l) {
  return index[i][j][k][l];
}
```

When I try to compile this under Visual Studio 2013, I get the strange internal compiler error

```
error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code -1073740940.
```

or, sometimes, also:

```
fatal error c1001 internal compiler error
```

Now, if I change my code only a little bit, for example, in the first lines:

```
  int i;
  for (int a = 0; a < 9; a++) {
    i = a;
    [...]
  }
```

it compiles without problem.

Can someone understand what the origin of the problem is?

Here the minimal code with which I reproduce it:

foo.h:

```
class foo{
 public:
  static void setIndexes();
  static unsigned int getIndex(int i, int j, int k, int l);

 private:
  static void setUniqueIndexes();
  static void setIndex(int i, int j, int k, int l, unsigned int *p);
  static unsigned int index[9][9][9][9];
};
```

foo.cpp:

```
#include "foo.h"

unsigned int foo::index[9][9][9][9];

void foo::setIndexes() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < 9; k++) {
        for (int l = 0; l < 9; l++) {
          index[i][j][k][l] = 100;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  setUniqueIndexes();

  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < 9; k++) {
        for (int l = 0; l < 9; l++) {
          if (index[i][j][k][l] != 100) {
            setIndex(i, j, k, l, &index[j][i][k][l]);
            setIndex(i, j, k, l, &index[i][j][l][k]);
            setIndex(i, j, k, l, &index[j][i][l][k]);
            setIndex(i, j, k, l, &index[k][l][i][j]);
            setIndex(i, j, k, l, &index[k][l][j][i]);
            setIndex(i, j, k, l, &index[l][k][i][j]);
            setIndex(i, j, k, l, &index[l][k][j][i]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

void foo::setIndex(int i, int j, int k, int l, unsigned int *p) {
  *p = getIndex(i,j,k,l);
}

unsigned int foo::getIndex(int i, int j, int k, int l) {
  return index[i][j][k][l];
}

void foo::setUniqueIndexes() {
  index[0][0][0][0] = 0;
}
```

What is really strange is also that it compiles if I comment out one of the previous parts of function `setIndexes()` or if I delete the statement in `setUniqueIndexes()`!

NB: the code as such does not make much sense, I reduced it to the minimum that reproduces the error

Comment: The exit code looks like gibberish, but the MSB6006 led me to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13118947/error-msb6006-cmd-exe-exited-with-code-1) question, which might help you. Emphasis on "might"; this is an incredibly weird problem.

Comment: My VS2010 seems to compile the code just fine, at least not giving any errors  (but I haven't tried to run that).

Comment: Not sure if it's of any help, but the exit code translates to `0xC0000374`, which appears to be the exception code for a heap corruption of some sort.

Comment: With VS 2015 it runs just fine. As it does [here at Ideone](http://ideone.com/rPGZEK).

Comment: And yes, this code also runs with my VS 2013. Please provide a [better example as specified here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry for that; I included a minimal example that reproduces the error for me

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio

Comment: I can still compile this with VS 2013 and VS 2015.

Comment: Try to compile with the O2 flag activated