# MSBuild error MSB6006 when compiling project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, blazor, blazor-server-side, visual-studio-2022

I have a Blazor server-side project that was compiling just fine some moments ago. Now I am getting the following build error:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(80,5): error MSB6006: "csc.exe" exited with code -2146232797.

I can't find any information for the error code.

How can I set the verbosity level (`-verbosity:diag`) when building the project? And preferably, how can I solve the problem?

Comment: I want to say that sometimes deleting vs folder in your solution directory helps with errors like that.

Comment: I've deleted the vs, bin and obj folders. Nothing is helping.

Comment: Can't you revert to the earlier version (that did work) and figure out what has changed?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13118947/error-msb6006-cmd-exe-exited-with-code-1